# Using jQuery, Bootstrap and Sass in my Rails project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have installed all necessary gems to have jQuery, Sass and Bootstrap Sass in my rails project. However, I do not know how to start making use of them. I have also included all Bootstrap files in the assets pipeline and modified the files to import/require those files.

This is my `application.css.scss`:

```
@import "_bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "_bootstrap";
```

And this is my `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Now I have generated a controller and tried to use jQuery in it, straight without doing anything special, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function() { alert('Hello') })</script>
```

But apparently, I am doing something wrong. **Do I need to do some sort of inclusion of jQuery/Bootstrap/Stylesheets in my erb files?**

As said, I'm a novice in Rails and I'm looking to get started. Answers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is wrong? what does not work?

Comment: You do not have to include jQuery/Bootstrap/Stylesheets in your erb files. Those will be automatically included by the asset pipeline.

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin I cannot start writing jQuery right away in my erb files. Do I need to include jQuery in the erb files somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you added `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.0'` (at the time of this writing) to your Gemfile, ran `bundle install` in terminal and then restarted the rails server.

The rails way of doing things would then have you create a new file in your stylesheets asset pipeline `app\assets\stylesheets` and call it `custom.css.scss` (your choice of filename is up to you, but the file extension must end in css.scss).

Add the following contents to your `custom.css.scss` file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Add the following contents to your `application.css` file:

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

`*= require_tree .` adds everything in the stylesheet directory and `*= require_self` will include any lines of code you put in the application.css after the close of the requirements `*/`.

Next, you will also need to add bootstrap javascript.  In your `application.js` file, you need to include bootstrap in a specific order and using the proper names.  Reorder the file to look like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Assuming that you have already included the following lines at the top of your application layout

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

you should be good to go.